# Extra newline character for children of Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I use `BeautifulSoup` on a snippet of html as follows:

```
 s = """<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-  first">
            <span class="views-field views-field-title"> 
                <span class="field-content"><a href="/party-pictures/2015/love-heals">Love Heals</a>
                </span> 
            </span>
            <span class="views-field views-field-created"> 
                <span class="field-content">Friday, March 20, 2015
                </span> 
           </span> 
</div>""" 

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
```

Why does `s.span` only return the first span tag?

Moreover s.contents returns a list of length 4. Both span tags are in the list but the 0th and 2nd index are "\n$ new line characters. The new line character is useless. Is there a reason why this is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does s.span only return the first span tag?

`s.span` is a shortcut to [`s.find('span')`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) which would find *the first occurrence* of the `span` tag only.

> Moreover s.contents returns a list of length 4. Both span tags are in the list but the 0th and 2nd index are "\n$ new line characters. The new line character is useless. Is there a reason why this is done?

By definition, [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) outputs a list of all element's children, including text nodes - instances of [`NavigableString` class](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring).

If you want the tags only, you can use `find_all()`:

```
soup.find_all()
```

And, if only `span` tags:

```
soup.find_all('span')
```

Example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = """<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-  first">
...             <span class="views-field views-field-title"> 
...                 <span class="field-content"><a href="/party-pictures/2015/love-heals">Love Heals</a>
...                 </span> 
...             </span>
...             <span class="views-field views-field-created"> 
...                 <span class="field-content">Friday, March 20, 2015
...                 </span> 
...            </span> 
... </div>""" 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> for span in soup.find_all('span'):
...     print span.text.strip()
... 
Love Heals
Love Heals
Friday, March 20, 2015
Friday, March 20, 2015
```

The reason for the duplicates is that there are nested `span` elements. You can fix it in different ways. For example, you can make the search inside the `div` only with `recursive=False`:

```
>>> for span in soup.find('div', class_='views-row-1').find_all('span', recursive=False):
...     print span.text.strip()
... 
Love Heals
Friday, March 20, 2015
```

Or, you can make use of [`CSS Selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
>>> for span in soup.select('div.views-row-1 > span'):
...     print span.text.strip()
... 
Love Heals
Friday, March 20, 2015
```

Comment: soup.find_all('span') still does not work for me. I would have thought it would return a list of length 2 with the 2 span but I only get a list of length 1 which is of type bs4.element.ResultSet

Comment: @Ben I've made an update, hopefully, it will help in understanding.

Comment: thanks. this isn't as clean as I was hoping. It seems to me that there are two span tags which are direct children of the div tag. I'm thinking of this as a tree structure in the way I wrote the html.  I thought there would be a simple way to get these two subtrees just by calling .content() or .children() thanks for your help